# Android: Application closing unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity with a listview that displays the products registered with the images of the SDCARD. Some users are reporting that they receive the error "The application closed" while on this activity.

I've done all the tests to try to simulate it, and the error did not occur.
I thought it might be something with the device memory or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a class I developed long ago for catching errors in a jar file I had distributed to several friends.  It catches output to std out and stderr and writes it to a file.
If your users can use a file manager to find the file that is written they could send it to you.  I've done some preliminary testing on an app and it worked for me.
if you use it and have problems, please let me know.

```
package com.normstools;


import java.io.*;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class SaveStdOutput extends PrintStream {
  final static boolean    debug = false;      // controls debug output

  static OutputStream logfile;
  static PrintStream oldStdout = null;
  static PrintStream oldStderr = null;

  private boolean    echoOutput = true;     //Also output to old setting

  // Constructor - we're the only one that can use it!
  private SaveStdOutput(PrintStream ps, boolean echoOutput) {
       super(ps);
    this.echoOutput = echoOutput;   
//     System.out.println("SaveStdOutput constructor called");
  } // end Constructor

  //------------------------------------------------------------
  // Starts copying stdout and stderr to the file f.
  public static void start(String f) throws IOException {
      // Create/Open logfile.
      OutputStream os = new PrintStream(
                   new BufferedOutputStream(
                       new FileOutputStream(f, true)));  // append to current
      doCommon(os, true);        
 } // end start()

  // Copy STDOUT and STDERR to an output stream
  public static void start(OutputStream os) {
      doCommon(os, true);
  } // end start()
  public static void start(OutputStream os, boolean eO) {
      doCommon(os, eO);
  } // end start()

  //-------------------------------------------------------
 // Finish up
 private static void doCommon(OutputStream os, boolean echoOutput) {
      // Only allow to be called once
      if (oldStdout != null) {
          if (debug)
              System.err.println("SaveStdOutput start() called twice");
          return;                    // Exit if already open
      }
    logfile = os;
    // Save old settings.
    oldStdout = System.out;
    oldStderr = System.err;

    // Start redirecting the output.
    System.setOut(new SaveStdOutput(System.out, echoOutput));
    System.setErr(new SaveStdOutput(System.err, echoOutput));
  } // end doCommon()

  //--------------------------------------
  // Restores the original settings.
  public static void stop() {
      if (oldStdout == null) {
          if (debug)
              System.err.println("SaveStdOutput stop() called before start()");
          return;
      }
      System.setOut(oldStdout);
      oldStdout = null;              //Clear
      System.setErr(oldStderr);
      try {
           logfile.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.err.println("SaveStdOutput stop() ex " + ex.getMessage());
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  } // end stop()

  //   Override the PrintStream write methods
  public void write(int b) {
      try {
            logfile.write(b);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          setError();
      }
    if (echoOutput)
       super.write(b);
  } // end write()

  // PrintStream override.
  public void write(byte buf[], int off, int len) {
      try {
            logfile.write(buf, off, len);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          setError();
      }
    if (echoOutput)
       super.write(buf, off, len);  
  }  // end write()

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Following for testing SaveStdOutput class: Comment out when done!
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          // Start capturing characters into the log file.
          SaveStdOutput.start("log.txt");

          // Test it.
          System.out.println("Here's is some stuff to stdout. " 
                                  + new java.util.Date());
          System.err.println("Here's is some stuff to stderr.");
          System.out.println("Let's throw an exception...");
          new Exception().printStackTrace();
          throw new Exception("this is thrown");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          // Stop capturing characters into the log file 
          // and restore old setup.
          SaveStdOutput.stop();
      }
      System.out.println("This should be to console only!");
   } // end main() */
 }  // end class SaveStdOutput
```

The main() method has sample usage.

```
Call the start() method in onStart() and the close() method in onStop(),
or add menu items to control it.  Add a few calls to System.out.println()
and some try{}catch blocks with printStackTrace().
```

Answer (score 0):

Error "The application closed" occurs most of the time when **Android detects your application is not loading or responding** within 3-5 Seconds, you should try to check the availability of the SD card, space available, permission or even run some of the process in the background. **Rewrite your code to handle these situations** and it should work.